# Swift, functions not getting the information

Tags: swift, swift3

I have the following code. I want to know why when i call rBloc() in the Main class its not printing var a, but its printing an empty array. I tried making it private but that still doesn't work.

what my code is, is I have setArr() in the main function. which has an array of numbers. And in that Function, setArr() I call another function Blocks in a different class Levels. In Blocks it just puts the arr in to the var new. Then black in the Main class I call rBloc which just prints out the array.

```
class Main: SKScence{
 override func didMove(to view: SKView){
 setArr()

let y=Levels()
y.rBloc()
}
func setArr(){
var a=[1,2,3]
 let n=Levels()
 n.Blocks(arr:a)
}
    }

class Levels: SKScene {

 var new=[Int]()

func Blocks(arr:[Int]){
    new=arr
    new.append(4)
}

func rBloc(){
    print(new)

}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are initialising a new Levels SKScene object that's why. You should change your setArr function to this

```
func setArr() -> Levels {

    var a = [1,2,3]
    let n = Levels()
    n.Blocks(arr:a)
    return n
}
```

Then in your Main class

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView){

    let y = self.setArr()
    y.rBloc()
}
```

Comment: whats a tick? like a bug in my code. I gave you a checkmark though.